# Kotlin: Generic variable

Tags: generics, kotlin

Hello is it possible to create a generic variable with getter and setter

like this:

```
var myVar: T
    get() { return this }
    set(value) {
        executeCustomFunc<T>()
    }
```

And use like this:

```
var test = ""
var secondText = 1

myVar = test // (Now myVar he's of type String)
myVar = secondText // (Now myVar he's of type Int)
```

Comment: If you want to dynamically "change" the type of a variable, you need to use a common supertype (might be `Any` in the worst case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is not possible. You can use class with generic parameter:

```
class SomeClass<T> {
    var myVar: T? = null
        set(value) {
            executeCustomFunc(value)
            field = value
        }

    private fun executeCustomFunc(v: T?) {

    }
}
```

or use `Any` instead of generic type:

```
var myVar: Any? = null
    get() { return this }
    set(value) {
        executeCustomFunc(value)
        field = value
    }

private fun executeCustomFunc(v: Any?) {

}
```

Comment: I don't think so. We can make generic variable using this kind of syntax: "val destinationActivity: Class<*>". Main part is "*". This is not exact answer. But can be helpful in other situations.